# Spreadsheet Array Formula Tweak

Tags: arrays, excel, spreadsheet, array-formulas

Trying to tweak this array formula

```
=INDEX(D26:W26,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(D26:W26,D26:W26)), COUNTIF(D26:W26,D26:W26),0)) & "  Winner"
```

It works and returns AAA Winner

It is for a contest - This counts name entries in each cell and returns which person has the most votes in the range.

What I would like it to do is to put the text Winner first then AAA.

Also, this does not handle if there is a tie in which I would like it to say it is a tie and between who so - Tie Between AAA and BBB. Right now, if there is a tie, it simply lists the very first one...

Hope that makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just switch it to:

```
="Winner " & INDEX(D26:W26,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(D26:W26,D26:W26)), COUNTIF(D26:W26,D26:W26),0))
```

But for the Tie-Part it gets hard (you would need to check everything against each other... better just make a new small table which holds each participant and then the value (with countif) which then can be sorted...

Comment: Awesome. That worked great! So simple... I wish there was just as simple a solution for the tie situation.

Comment: As said... creating a new table with lined up names and their points would make it much easier... or you go with a UDF which I don't know if it is usable for you...

Comment: Thank you. I am not a coder as you can tell.  It indexes and counts the entries, then gives the results - listing the one with the highest count....that is fine for now but is there no code for the INDEX and / or the COUNTIF simply to count and output the two entries when there is a tie?. Something like, if equal - output both...

Comment: You would need to calculate the all values an compare them. Then depending of what you get  pick a format and calculate it again for output (for each format)... it would end up in an extreme long not understandable formula... looking at this, it would be smarter to use "helper cells/columns/rows"....